# show pop-out window every 60 sec using applescript

Tags: applescript

I want a pop-out to show every 60 sec or 3600 sec using

```
display dialog "Hello there!"
```

I want this pop-out to remind me to take a break, thats why I want to wait given seconds and after i close, to wait again given seconds

Comment: similar question already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718520/how-do-i-write-applescript-that-will-give-me-an-hourly-popup-alert

Answer (score 1):

```
repeat
    set delayTime to 60 # number of seconds between showings
    set giveUpTime to 10 # number of seconds to show dialog before giving up

    display dialog "Hello there!" giving up after giveUpTime
    delay delayTime
end repeat
```